# git mirror without history, but with tags

Tags: git

for some reason I want to create a git mirror of a project WITHOUT the history but keeping tags.

For instance:

```
History: A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H
           |     |   |  
Tags:      1     2   3
```

After mirroring this repository it should look like

```
History: B-E-G
         | | |
         1 2 3
```

Maybe it is also needed to create out of `[B|E|G]` some other messages, most propably the same as the tag have (if needed).

Is there any way to do this directly with git or do I have to script this?
My idea was that, starting with the most recent tag, I just rebase the history down to the next tag. Is this also possible when merging between two tags?

Answer (score 0):

In general the simplest way to move multiple refs at once (even if that's just one branch and the tags reachable by that branch) would be to use `git filter-branch`.

First, you would use the `--commit-filter` to "skip over" commits that don't have tags.  You need a script that can tell if a script has a tag.  You can use something like

```
git describe --exact-match --tags
```

and if this finds a match it will return 0 (and also print the tag name on stdout); so your filter can conditionally defer to either `commit-tree` or `skip-commit` depending on whether a tag is found.

You would then need to add a `--tag-name-filter cat` or something similar to make the tags actually move.

For details about `filter-branch` see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

This is kinda-sorta like carefully scripting a bunch of rebase operations, with an automated way to map the tags.  It works well because you don't want to change the content (`TREE`) of the commits you keep, so the main rebase machinery isn't really needed.